# Is this possible to use recaptcha without internet connection

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I'm working on core php. I want to use recaptcha for my form. I downloaded recaptcha from [this link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php). It works fine but when I switched off my internet connection it's invisible on my local.

Is it possible to use recaptcha on my local server?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because the recaptcha images are picked from google. you could use normal captcha instead.

Comment: recaptcha is hosted by google.  You'll have to have internet

Answer (score 3):

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js is the reCaptcha js controller that makes all the reCaptcha management.
It is loaded from google server once and you **might** pre-load it and plug in locally. Yet, all the verification is done **server-side by google**, so you can't actually click recaptcha *off-line*, nor verify human-bot, neither submit a form.

Read [more](https://webscraping.pro/no-captcha-recaptcha-challenge) on reCaptcha v2.0

Answer (score 2):

Your Question is somehow strange. I think you have not the slightest idea what recaptcha is. Recapcha is a defense tool to block access to a online content to bots and other not human clients. If you switched off your internet connection you have absolute closed any possibility that a bot access your online content.
On the other hand if the bots and the automatic non-human visitors are inside your intranet you are a very special case, and probably you should tell us more about your very special case.

Comment: For me the question is will my site run as is , without code modifications, in such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Recaptcha is a service. Each request is handled by a foreign server, so no chance without an internet connection.

btw: A website without internet connection is not a real scenario ;)
If you use external services, you must have a chance to reach them.

Comment: A website in an intranet, is not real?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could think of is to provide a configuration or environment variable what would disable the use of recaptcha entirely. When you are working without Internet connection you would simple enable that configure option and develop your application without recaptcha.

Answer (score 0):

Well recaptcha is basically a google service and ofcourse it requires internet connection,wehreas if you want to work with `captcha` on your local server then try this link [Captcha](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/).

It works on your local server too :)

Answer (score -1):

I think if we are able to download the recaptcha/api.js file, and then store it on our local machine as we do with some of other js file, then can we still not able to use the service without internet.

during using google recaptch we say this in the head section.
    https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'> 
   but from where to download the js file and to like this